# convert desktop application to web based application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I developped a desktop application based on openJump and i want to convert my Desktop application to Web-based (browser enabled) application. I am just a child in Web technologies.
PLZ is there's any possibilities to do that? and to connect to the application via the web.
thanks in advance.

Comment: A shortcut would be to use Java WebStart. It is **not** a web application but it enables you to start your application from a browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking a easy porting from desktop to web based, then im afraid your out of luck. You will have to go through some popular web frameworks such as Struts or Spring MVC that will help you understand how to structure your web application. Of course you must be able to port your business logic to the web application without much change i hope. Try a few tutorials and first start with a normal Hello World. Good luck.